# How difficult to recreate messages.app image picker

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

out of curiosity how difficult is it to recreate this: (any git available?)

[image]

[image]

one of the app feature was to upload a photo we are think to mirror the design but not sure if is worth the effort.

an comments are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the first image you can use something like:

https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController

It uses AVFoundation which makes it more flexible

For the second image you'd need to use the Photos framework and put the photos into a UICollectionView

Example of UICollectionView usage:

https://github.com/halcyonmobiledev/HMCollectionViewCollageLayout